# Selecting Muliple Itme from Single Id from Sql Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have multiple products from 1 vendor, vendor id is falling into Product table, i want select vendor having multiple product, help me! my mind is not working!

[image]

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Request you to provide schema, sample data and desired result.

Comment: There is no picture because new users are blocked from adding them for exactly this reason, sample data should be supplied in text format, not as an image, ideally as a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtiZI.png -

Comment: It seems that you simply need to learn about [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.supplierid = t.supplierid AND t1.materialid <> t.materialid);
```

Comment: Thanks Alot !! this is what i needed !

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with aggregation:

```
select supplierid 
from table t
where MAMaterial in ('BUN', 'BEEF')
group by suppierid
having count(*) = 2;  -- number of materials in list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Select supplerid from table
where MAMaterial in ('BUN', 'BEEF')
```

or

```
select TOP 1 supplerid from table
where MAMaterial in ('BUN', 'BEEF')
```

Comment: not only BEEF ,BUN , i meant to say * get all the saved material by supplierid !

Comment: Thanks for Help Fa!